# Return vue component from a function

Tags: vue.js, templates, jsx, vuejs3

I'm new to Vue and I would want to render an SVG icon depending on task status and would like to create a re-usable function for that, How can I do that?

In React I could have done something like this:

```
const iconStatusMapping = {
  todo: <svg></svg>,
  processing: <svg>...</svg>,
  done: <svg>...</svg>
}

// utils.ts
export const getTaskStatusIcon = (status: TaskStatus) => {
  return iconStatusMapping[status]
}

function App() {
  const status = "todo"

  return (
    <div>{getTaskStatusIcon(status)} {status}</div>
  )
}
```

How can I do something similar in Vue3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React, it may be not a good idea to define reused elements as JSX that is not wrapped in a function because element objects are expected to be new on every render. This may have no consequences for SVG icons but may have unexpected behaviour in [other cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56020455/reused-react-element-prevents-component-updates).

In Vue, this snippet could be directly translated to render function and JSX.

Static HTML like SVG icons can be safely defined as strings and outputted with Vue `v-html`, the same applies to React `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`:

```
const iconStatusMapping = {
  todo: `<svg></svg>`,
  ...
}
```

and

```
v-html="iconStatusMapping[status]"
```

Comment: Sounds good, but what if I want to provide props to that, Let's instead of that being an SVG icon let's say it's a component? Thank you.

Comment: Then a status should likely be mapped to a whole component i.e. `todo: TodoIcon`, and used like dynamic component, `<component :is="iconStatusMapping[status]" v-bind="{...}"/>`. The same approach is applicable to React.